# How can I remove this scrollbar?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

I am working on visual studio 2010. The code was running perfectly but, suddenly I don't know why a horizontal scroll bar appeared. Does anyone have any idea how to remove the scroll bar. Below is my code. Thanks for your help

```
<%@ Page Title="Reports" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Reports.aspx.cs" Inherits="F.Reports" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".dateFrom").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
            $(".dateTo").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
     Reports</h2>
    <div id="Div4" style="position: absolute; left: 310px; margin-top: 40px;">
        <h3>
            From Date
        </h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="DateField" class="dateFrom" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    <div id="Div3" style="position: absolute; left: 500px; margin-top: 40px;">
        <h3>
            To Date
        </h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="DateField2" class="dateTo" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
        </asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    <div id="Div1" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; margin-top: 40px; right: 295px;">
        <h3>
            Choose Report</h3>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ReportDropDownList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Report1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Report2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Report3 </asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" style="position: relative; left: 690px; margin-top: 55px;">
        <asp:Button ID="GenerateReportButton" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="GenerateReportButton_Click" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Your question has many problems: **1.** your question isn't really clear about the scrollbar issue? Is it horizontal or vertical scrollbar. Is it in Visual studio (since you're mentioning it) or is it the browser (that you don't mention at all). Which element seems to be showing scrollbar (check with FireBug). **And 2.** Your code doesn't really help. It would be better to put it in JSFiddle so we could actually see the problem (if it's the browser issue). _I could put this as an answer since it does answer a few things but I won't since it's more of a help to you._

Comment: it is a horizontal scrollbar and it happens in the browser. Sorry for not mentioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set overflow: hidden;. Otherwise, Setting overflow: auto will cause scrollbars to show whenever they are needed.

That should fix it.

Answer (score 5):

In order to hide the horizontal scroll bar in a webbrowser, you can insert `style="overflow-x:hidden"` into the `<html>` tag, but not in the `<body>` tag.

i.e. `<html style="overflow-x:hidden">` **will allow** you to disable the horizontal scroll bar

i.e. `<body style="overflow-x:hidden">` will **not** yield the disable effect

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS style overflow: hidden; to remove the scrollbar. The information that doesnt fit in the DIV wont be displayed. You can also remove the fixed div height to solve the problem.

Comment: Well it seems (as he commented) the width is the problem not height.